# Use Javascript object variable for an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to display information of a shop basket. I know how to pull the data and create elements from it, but I need to use one of the variables for an `if` statement, and am unsure how to.

If this is `true`: `"isPunchOut": false,` then I want to target that with jQuery, and do something like `$(".button").remove();`

How do I do this?

```
var retailerData = {
"del": {
    "zip": "",
    "city": ""
},
"user": {
    "country": "",
    "phone": "",
    "nbrOrders": 0,
    "isPunchOut": false,
    "name": "",
    "salesPerson": "",
    "customerNo": "",
    "email": ""
},
"order": {
    "shippingSum": 0.0,
    "shippingFormatSum": "\u20AC0",
    "orderno": "0",
    "orderFormatSum": "\u20AC130",
    "voucher": "",
    "orderFormatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
    "currencySymbol": "\u20AC",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "orderVat": 27.3,
    "orderSum": 130.0,
    "items": [{
        "imageURI": "\/imgr\/8c82380c-65f5-43aa-83ad-fae1215b5b39\/70\/70",
        "qtyAvail": 7,
        "price": 130.0,
        "qty": 1,
        "artno": "D630-T7100-GE-REF",
        "vat": 27.3,
        "formatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
        "id": "52307",
        "label": "D630 C2D-T7100&#x2F;2GB&#x2F;80GB&#x2F;DVD&#x2F;14&#34;&#x2F;NO COA WLAN",
        "category": "Computers - Notebooks",
        "formatPrice": "\u20AC130",
        "manufacturer": "Dell"
    }]
  }
 }
```

Comment: jQuery and HTML in a [mcve] please.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at below JS code for reference:

```
var isPunchOut = retailerData["user"]["isPunchOut"];
if(isPunchOut === false)
    $(".button").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should try some code first and put where you get stuck .We not here to write code for your problems.

```
var retailerData = {
"del": {
    "zip": "",
    "city": ""
},
"user": {
    "country": "",
    "phone": "",
    "nbrOrders": 0,
    "isPunchOut": false,
    "name": "",
    "salesPerson": "",
    "customerNo": "",
    "email": ""
},
"order": {
    "shippingSum": 0.0,
    "shippingFormatSum": "\u20AC0",
    "orderno": "0",
    "orderFormatSum": "\u20AC130",
    "voucher": "",
    "orderFormatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
    "currencySymbol": "\u20AC",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "orderVat": 27.3,
    "orderSum": 130.0,
    "items": [{
        "imageURI": "\/imgr\/8c82380c-65f5-43aa-83ad-fae1215b5b39\/70\/70",
        "qtyAvail": 7,
        "price": 130.0,
        "qty": 1,
        "artno": "D630-T7100-GE-REF",
        "vat": 27.3,
        "formatVat": "\u20AC27,30",
        "id": "52307",
        "label": "D630 C2D-T7100&#x2F;2GB&#x2F;80GB&#x2F;DVD&#x2F;14&#34;&#x2F;NO COA WLAN",
        "category": "Computers - Notebooks",
        "formatPrice": "\u20AC130",
        "manufacturer": "Dell"
    }]
  }
 }

if(retailerData.user.isPunchOut){
//your jquery operation
}
```

Check[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0h3ty72/)

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
   if (!retailerData.user.isPunchOut) { 
        $(".button").remove();
   }
```